# Bash: Move files based on first letter of name

Tags: bash

I have a large amount of files which I am trying to organize into three folders alphabetically. I'm trying to get a bash script together which has the ability to get the first letter of the file, then move it into a folder based on that first letter.

For example:

file ->  folder name

apples -> A-G

banana -> A-G

tomato -> H-T

zebra  -> U-Z

Any tips would be appreciated! TIA!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? How did `A-G`, `H-T`, and `U-Z` be decided? What happens for files outside those starting letters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
dirs=(A-G H-T U-Z)
shopt -s nocasematch

for file in *
do
    for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
    do
        if [[ $file =~ ^[$dir] ]]
        then
            mv "$file" "$dir"
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: May I suggest just checking if each file is in fact one of the dirs you just created...    
`  if [ -d "$file" ]; then`

Comment: @AndyD: Your comment doesn't seem to match the answer or the question.

Comment: Sorry - the comments here won't let me put in nicely formatted code, I'll try this: for file in * will find the Directories themselves, resulting in a bad mv - trying to move the directory into itself. I'm suggesting (and used myself) a slight change to the script to wrap the "for dir" loop in a **If**, checking if this **file** is in fact one of the directories and if so, break and look at the next **file.** This works much better for me and I think anyone else doing this.

Comment: This is a great script, very clean and simple. I also created a dir per letter, so my dirs array was =(A B C D E F... Z) and it works great. I love it. Moved about 10,000 files from one mess that was super slow into a nicely organized 26 directories.

Comment: @AndyD: By the way, a quick way to populate your array is `dirs=({A..Z})` using a range rather than listing each one individually.

Answer (score 2):

You want [substring expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and a [case statement](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs). For example:

```
thing=apples
case ${thing:0:1} in
    [a-gA-G]) echo "Do something with ${thing}." ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding my code - this is 99% based on  Dennis Williamson - I just added an if block to make sure you are not moving a dir into a target dir, and I wanted a dir per letter.

```
#!/bin/bash
dirs=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)
shopt -s nocasematch

for file in *
do
    for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
    do

     if [ -d "$file" ]; then
      echo 'this is a dir, skipping'
      break
     else
      if [[ $file =~ ^[$dir] ]]; then
       echo "----> $file moves into -> $dir <----"
       mv "$file" "$dir"
       break
      fi
     fi
  done
done
```

Comment: Totally fits my bill!